quotient groupoid as the colimit in the infinite category Grpd
For a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, there is set theoretic quotient $X/G$ defined as the colimit of the following diagram in the category $Set$: 
But this set forgets how two elements in the same orbit are related, so we need to introduce the 'quotient groupoid' $[X/G]$ constructed intuitively as follows :
Consider the equivalence relation on $X$ as $R\subset X\times X$
$\cdot$ The objects of $[X/G]$ are the elements of $X$.
$\cdot$ The morphisms of $[X/R]$ are the elements of $R$.
$\cdot$ The source and target map of morphism are given by $pr_{1}$ and $pr_{2}$.
$\cdot$ The identity map sending an object to its identity morphism is given by the diagonal morphism.
This is a very concrete construction while there is a more categorical description on this 'quotient groupoid' saying that '$[X/G]$ is the colimit of the above diagram in the infinity category $Grpd$.'
$\textbf{Question}$:
I don't know how to prove this statement or is there any concrete way to describe the colimit in $Grpd$ (as (2,1) category or infinity category constructed by its Duskin nerve) ?

Does this help? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+groupoid#as_a_pseudo_colimit I think you simply need to show the universal property.

Oh , that's great help, I should google 'action groupoid' instead of 'quotient groupoid'.

(Homotopy) colimits of diagrams of groupoids are computed by the Thomason homotopy colimit theorem as the Grothendieck construction of the diagram.
In the case under consideration, the diagram must be first enhanced to a 3-term diagram, including the term $G⨯G⨯X$ (otherwise the claim stated in the main post is false).  Then the Grothendieck construction of the resulting diagram is equivalent to the action groupoid.
A book that covers these topics: From Categories to Homotopy Theory (Birgit Richter).

Thanks for your answer and reference, I just want to ask what it means here when you say the ‘ diagram must be enhanced to three terms, otherwise the claim is false’. The ‘claim’  you mean here is the conclusion ‘colimit of the (two) term diagram is action groupoid’ or the Thomason homotopy limit theorem?

@Yang: The claim about the colimit stated in the main post: '[X/G] is the colimit of the above diagram in the infinite category Grpd.'
